Обработка sql-дампа bash-скриптом
Имеется sql-дамп маленького веса(200кб)
Нужно написать скрипт, который изменит пароли в дампе на случайные символы, все пароли лежат в определенных строках - 16 по счету группа символов
И еще изменит имена и фамилии на какие-либо еще - имя и фамилия тоже находятся в фиксированном по счету месте 12 и 13 - (например, будет брать имена и фамилии из какого-нибудь файла, в котором может быть 10 имен и фамилий, есть условие, чтобы имена и фамилии были осмысленными, поэтому их можно записать вручную в файле, и затем использовать файл как переменную)
Вот таких строчек 1000:
insert into MOCK_DATA (id, first_name, last_name, email, gender, password, company_name) values (1000, 'Hobard', 'O''Loinn', 'holoinnrr@japanpost.jp', 'Male', 'yJ3=(fVV$X8k8wur#OCo4q#A/Q', 'Meedoo');


У тебя что, дамп есть, а сервера нету? уж что проще - загрузить дамп, запросом всё зарандомить, выгрузить обратно...

Нет, сервера нет, разве что сделать это локально

Вообще не реклама, есть куча сервисов, например aiven.io который предоставит совсем бесплатно любую БД (ограниченного размера конечно).. Создайте БД и подключитесь например к ней через mysql workbench.. или даже с https://onecompiler.com/mysql мб что выйдет

@Jour выгружать пароли открытым текстом на какой-то левый сервис — максимально странно

@andreymal ничего не мешает базу удалить сразу после ее создания) но вы правы, конфиденциальную инфу я бы там не светил вообще) мб поставить БД себе на ПК человек не может.. хотя это наиболее быстрый и простой способ) вообще, если так рассмотреть, безопасно - это если ПК без сети в сейфе установлен, и то не факт))

Попробуйте awk, пример:
$ echo '1 2 3 4 5' | awk '{$3="AAA";print}'
1 2 AAA 4 5

В этом примере 3-й элемент заменяется на ААА
